# Charmed Distribution Of Kubernetes on LXC and Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, lxc

I am trying to get a decent solution of exposing my services from a Kubernetes cluster hosted on local LXC containers.

The setup is as follows:

Host: Ubuntu 18.04 running a LXC cluster.

Inside the LXC there is a Charmed Distribution Of Kubernetes which is running my apps and another container running a NGINX reverse proxy.

I've also setup a Metallb load-balancer inside kubernetes and use all k8s services which needs internet exposing as `LoadBalancer`:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: blazedesk
  name: blazedesk-sdeweb-server
  labels:
    app: blazedesk
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: "http"
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    name: "https"
  selector:
    app: blazedesk
    tier: sdeweb-server
  type: LoadBalancer`

How I did it so far was to redirect all http and https traffic coming to the main host to NXGINX reverse-proxy:

`lxc config device add proxy myport80 proxy listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:80 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:80 proxy_protocol=true`

`lxc config device add proxy myport443 proxy listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:443 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:443 proxy_protocol=true`

Nginx is then configured to redirect traffic matching DNS addresses to k8s services external-ips:

```
NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
service/blazedesk-sdeweb-server    LoadBalancer   10.152.183.215   10.190.26.240   80:31476/TCP,443:31055/TCP   17d
```

`proxy_pass https://10.190.26.240;`

As you can imagine, this setup implies lots of manual work, especially if the k8s services are restarted and new ips are allocated by metallb loadbalancer.

Is there a simpler way to redirect the traffic from the hosts directly to a kubernetes ingress, somehow bypassing LXC layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually made it work with an NGINX ingress controller exposed as a LoadBalancer service and redirect http and https traffic from host,  using iptables, to the ingress external-ip.